# Symfony2 Cached Sessions not Garbage Collecting causing Disk Full issues

Tags: php, symfony, garbage-collection, diskspace

So the application is not doing anything with caching, I'm just using the default framework setting in config.yml

```
framework:
    # ...
    session:         ~
```

Looking in the

```
project/app/cache/prod/session
```

directory I see session files from 6 months ago and it's causing a DISK FULL error/issue.

If I run the command

```
df -h
```

The disk space looks fine, if I run the command

```
df -i
```

I see it's full or almost full

for the php.ini it's all default settings, running ubuntu 12.04 LTS and PHP 5.3.x

Why isn't the Garbage Collection working? When I clear the Cache it's fine and cleans up but to my understanding the session should be removed after 4 hours, any ideas?

Comment: Found this on the subject: http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/keep-symfony2-sessions-through-cache-clear/

Comment: @cheesemacfly Thanks but the link you provided saves or extends the session, I wanted to know why my sessions are not being removed/expiring and not being cleaned up by the Garbage Collection process

Comment: Well yes, what I was referring to was the comment section of the article: `But what about clearing all useless session files?` -> `Try something like this to delete one week old session files (modification date): $ find /…/app/var/sessions/* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;`. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @cheesemacfly I know I can manually remove the file, I'm asking why don't they automatically get cleaned up? I don't think a session should be cached for 6 months. Thanks for the link though

Comment: I might be wrong but after a little research (and I checked on my server running a ubuntu 12.04 as well) I found that the cron job under `/etc/cron.d/php5` which is the one cleaning the session folder on ubuntu only looks into the `/var/lib/php5/` folder. That would be the reason why!

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else has this issue here is how to fix it:

Here is what is configured in

- /etc/php5/apache/php.ini
- /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

( All three are the same )

```
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

I also looked in to

```
/etc/cron.d/php5
```

and it should remove the sessions using this value `session.gc_maxlifetime`

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete
```

The problem is my sessions are not in the standard location and are not cleaned up because of this.

Configuring the framwerwork session save_path to:

```
/var/lib/php5
```

You can also set this value to the save_path of your php.ini by setting the value to null:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        save_path: null
```

Docs:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#gc-divisor

Comment: You can use `null` to set this value to the `save_path` of your php.ini: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#save-path